# Memory is allocation : heap or stack?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct number
{
    int value;
    int pos;
public:
    number(int a,int b)
    {
        value=a;
        pos=b;
    }
};
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    number(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

where is memory allocated in this case for `number(1,2)`? On heap or stack? How do we verify it?

Comment: There is no such thing as heap or stack in C++.  We have objects with automatic storage duration and dynamic storage duration.

Comment: Im pretty sure it is entirely dependant on compiler and OS. So no way of knowing.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from a couple of C++ standard library functions, C++ doesn't have a notion of a *stack* or a *heap*.

Some folk equate things allocated with `new` as being on the *heap* and all others as allocated on the *stack*. But `static` storage and other bits and pieces muddy that crude categorisation.

In your case `number(1, 2);` is an anonymous temporary and has automatic storage duration. A good compiler might notice that there is no side effect in the construction or destruction of the anonymous temporary and so might remove it altogether from the compiled binary. So a third option - *no memory at all* - seems likely to me.